# Deliver iPhone app to the app store with Facebook account

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval

We're about to deliver an application to the app store.

To enjoy the app, the user have to enter a Facebook login info (Using Facebook-connect API for iPhone).

Now, to deliver the app to Apple's app store, they (Apple) ask us to provide a username+password (account info) for testing issues.

That's great, but, since our app based on Facebook account info and not our own database, **do we have to provide a Facebook account info**?? because if the answer is YES, it means that we have to open a fake account in Facebook.

So, does anyone know the answer?

***Do we have to provide a Facebook account info in the Apple's application upload form?***

Comment: It depends on the person who will review your app. I don't think it's necessary, but if you want to be 100 % sure, just provide it. It costs nothing and you can avoid rejecting your app.

Comment: yeah, but it means opening a fake FB account.. i don't like that idea too..

Comment: Please consider joining [the App Store proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores) on Area 51.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar thought when delivering an app that interacted with Twitter. In the user account box on iTunesConnect I wrote something like "Enter the details of any Twitter account" and it passed the app store validation process fine.

Answer (score 1):

We submitted several apps to the store that required a Facebook account and we supplied Apple with an account that we just created. However, from our logs, the Apple reviewers logged in with their own accounts :)

To be on the safe side, I would suggest that you create a fake Facebook account and add in the reviewer's notes textfield, better safe than sorry.